# Power BI - Create multiple measures at once based on the result of a calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI and kindly request assistance

I have a job table that has a type column (on-site, remote or hybrid) and a vacancy location column by State

I know how the CALCULATE method works and I know how to individually create measures to do this, something similar to this

```
 hybrid_job_california_state = CALCULATE(
   COUNTROWS(job), job[type]="hybrid"
 )
```

However, I imagine there is a simpler way to do this, I wouldn't want to replicate the same code over and over again to get the total for each State

I read about GROUPBY, but I couldn't understand how to apply it to this situation

Is there any way for me to have the sum of jobs by state without having to manually create a measure for each state?

Comment: I would use a matrix visual for this. Put job[type] on the columns and [state] on the rows, and then your measure in the values. What happens when you do that is that the visual creates an evaluation context for each "intersection" (combination of one state and one job[type]), and filters down and calculates the quantity for each "cell".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstand:

In the simplest way, the visual will do the filtering and aggregation for you.

e.g., if you create a table visual with ‘job’[type] in one column and in the second column any column from ‘job’ aggregated by COUNT it will count with respect to the job type.

Otherwise, you may want to have a look on the
`ALLEXCEPT ()` to apply/set the filter in your measure explicitly.

Good luck!

Edit: both work with multiple criteria, i.e. if you add the state in another column in the table visual, it’s included to the filtering as well